# Pass sql as string to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller I have:

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from table");
```

I want to have a file `myquery.sql` in which the only contents of that file are:

```
select * from table
```

And so I can do something like:

```
$query = $this->db->query(myquery.sql);
```

What is the right syntax to do this?

Comment: As for why, the query I'm using is 700 lines and I didn't want it to make my otherwise concise controller difficult to navigate through. I wanted to use a stored procedure but couldn't get it to work and read somewhere that stored procedures don't play nice with Code Igniter, but maybe one day I'll try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that using:

```
$query = $this->db->query(file_get_contents('myquery.sql'));
```

Read more about [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

---

You might need to use the correct path to `myquery.sql`, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks guys, that got it to work. It literally required the full path all the way down to the drive letter though, which is annoying...why can't I just use the filename like I can with an include statement?

Comment: @DavidBrooks TBH, I don't know how to answer that path problem. Maybe codeigniter is messing things up, but I really don't know.